# Heat Pump - Air Handler circulates when using emergency heat

Tags: heat-pump, heat

I have a Bosch Heat Pump that was installed this past summer with a Resideo thermostat.  When I try to run my fossil fuel heat source (baseboard forced hot water), it turns the fan on to circulate air.  The only problem with this is that it wakes up my kids when it kicks on or off.

When the technician installed it, he showed me the removal of a panel on the air handler and said to to switch the green fan line to the yellow wire during winter.  I tried this, but the air handler still turns on.  Maybe I misheard him as I was dealing with madness with the kids.

I just want to run my fossil fuel source without the air handler turning on.  Any HVAC guys familiar with this issue?

Comment: It will help us to answer your question if you provide the actual model of your air handler, and a diagram of how it is wired to your thermostat. Or you can call the installer and ask them to explain it again.

Comment: I'm puzzled a little as to why the air handler operating at other times (summer air conditioning, cool-season heat pump heating) would not wake the kids but they do wake when the blower runs along with the baseboard heat (if the former cases wake them also, one would guess you'd be here asking "how do I disable my air handler at night" or similar). But that aside, if you'd share with us photos showing the thermostat connections to the air handler and baseboard system, we may be able to help you figure out how to re-configure it.